# ftell function giving -1 in C for stdout

Tags: c, popen

I want to wget in C and I am using popen to do so.

```
FILE *stdoutPtr = popen(command,"r");
fseek(stdoutPtr, 0L, SEEK_END);
long pos = ftell(stdoutPtr);
```

Here I want to get the size of `stdout` so that I can initialize buffer. But `pos` variable is always -1.
`pos` is supposed to tell me current position of read pointer.

Please help....

Comment: ftell is an I/O function for determining the current position in a stream. -1 indicates an error. You can read the exact error using perror and the global errno.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `FILE` returned by `popen` is not a regular file, but a thing called a [`pipe`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/pipe).  (That's what the `p` stands for.)  Data flows *through* the pipe from the stdout of the command you invoked to your program.  Because it's a communications channel and not a file on disk, a pipe does not have a definite size, and you cannot seek to different locations in the data stream.  Therefore, [`fseek` and `ftell`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ftell) will both fail when applied to this `FILE`, and that's what a `-1` return value means.  If you inspect `errno` immediately after the call to `ftell` you will discover that it has the value `ESPIPE`, which means "You can't do that to a pipe."

If you're trying to read all of the output from the command into a single `char*` buffer, the only way to do it is to repeatedly call one of the read functions until it indicates end-of-file, and enlarge the buffer as necessary using `realloc`.  If the output is potentially large, it would be better to change your program to process the data in chunks, if there's any way to do that.

Comment: "fseek and ftell will both fail when applied to this FILE, and that's what a -1 return value means" - any authoritative quote on this (like C or other standard)?

Comment: @pfalcon Is the text under **ERRORS** at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fseek.html what you're looking for?  (Note what it says at "[ESPIPE]".)

Comment: And I hope feof() works as expected on popen()ed FILEs: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/feof.html doesn't give any exceptions, and from description, it would work like: when fread() would return 0 for EOF, it sets EOF flag on FILE, and feof() just returns that, so this handling is indeed not pipe-specific.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use pipes that way. For one thing, the information would be obsolete the instant you got it, since more data could be written to the pipe by then. You have to use a different allocation strategy.

The most common strategy is to allocate a fixed-size buffer and just keep reading until you reach end of file. You can process the data as you read it, if you like.

If you need to process the data all in one chunk, you can allocate a large buffer and start reading into that. If it does get full, then use `realloc` to enlarge the buffer and keep going until you have it all.

A common pattern is to keep a buffer pointer, a buffer count, and an allocation size. Initially, set the allocation size to, say, 64K. Set the count to zero. Allocate a 64K buffer. Read up to `size-count` bytes into the buffer. If you hit EOF, stop. If the buffer is nearly full, bump up the allocation size by 50% and `realloc` the buffer.